# Value was either too large or too small for a UInt32: TFS Checkin Error

Tags: tfs

When I'm trying to check in some code TFS and below error message is coming.

> **Value was either too large or too small for a UInt32.**

What is causing this issue and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Same happening with Visual Studio 2015 using git

Answer (score 263, accepted):

I have found the solution for this issue.

**Solution:**

> Save your files before check-in and then initiate check in. This issue
>   will not come.

**Root Cause:**

> It seems to be a bug in the dialog (Not sure), but certainly error
>   message is confusing to user.

Hope this solution will resolve your issue.

Comment: "This is fine.  I'm okay with the events that are unfolding currently."

Comment: Please note that this does not only involve the sources being checked in; also verify any 'excluded' pending changes in the same workspace have been saved before checking in, otherwise you may still face the same error.

Comment: I had to save the solution file itself to resolve the issue. I added a project to the solution and forgot to save.

Comment: File > Save All

Answer (score 17):

As Geeky Ninja mentions, the problem is that not all files are saved. Luckily VS has a handy button for this (ctrl + shift + s):

```
File > Save All
```

Helps me every time

Answer (score 3):

Build and check in. You will not see the problem. It's always good to
see your changes are actually compiled with no errors before checking in.

Answer (score 0):

Weird error.  In my case it was when I tried to Shelf my code.  I just ran the solution to ensure it worked before I created a shelfset.  I then tried to create a shelfset in so all the files were saved, I thought.

I did the Save All and actually restarted Visual Studio. Then Chrome hung as Visual Studio was starting ... I was finally able to create my shelfset update.